# Web Starter Kit - where to write sass?

Tags: javascript, sass, gulp

I'm starting to play around with Googles 'Web Starter Kit' I'm familiar with tools such as grunt/yeoman/bower. With WSK i'm confused as to where I would write sass code? All I see is files h5bp.css and main.css and the components folder. How do I make it so I can use sass/scss then when I run/serve the site if compiles it into css?

Thanks for any help, still new to this stuff.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your SASS in `app/styles`. In your HTML, you need to link to the file, with the same filename but a `.css` extension. For example, if you wrote your SASS in `app/styles/style.scss`, in your HTML you'd want to link it like this: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" />`

Comment: Ok great thanks :) Then not use main.css and h5bp.css files? Isn't it just adding more bloat having those files there too?

Answer (score 0):

When considering where to include *my* SASS code I thought, "why not put it in the cool little spot in the _h5bp.scss files' *Author's custom styles* area." After seeing that my changes where having no effect, I noticed that the @import in main.scss for the h5bp.scss partial still had the underscore in front of it, and of course it wasn't being imported.

> @import '_h5bp';

I removed the underscore an yep, it worked fine.
To me this seemed like a great place to put my code, but...

There is allot of css in the main.scss file that overwrites many things I want to change, so I just started making my changes in the main.scss file.